# Chrome Extension Tab Deleting Not Working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Ok, So I was working on deleting tabs with a Chrome Extension, but it's not working. Here's my code for each file.

backround.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "bookmarklet.js"})
```

});

bookmarklet.js

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("unblocked", "games", "1v1", "smash carts", "slope unblocked", "retrobowl",) > -1) {
alert("You are not supposed to be on the website. You will be reported to an adminstrator immediatly.");
console.log(window.location.href)
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function() { });
});
```

}else {
console.log("This Website is Safe")
}`enter code here`

My question is, how am I supposed to get the chrome. tab. remove function to work? Also my mainfest.json includes the tab permissions.

Comment: Move the code that uses chrome.tabs into the callback of executeScript.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can I have a example

Comment: is this how you do it?
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "bookmarklet.js"})
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function() { });
    });
});

Comment: You can't use the chrome.tabs.remove method in the script that is injected into the website. Send a message back to the background and from there remove the tab.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am not familiar with javascript